# Current state of Facebook OpenID support

Tags: facebook, openid

I'm reading conflicting reports of Facebook OpenID support. A Facebook [blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/246) from 2009 states that they do, but apparently there is OAuth and Facebook Connect. Or do they only support *other* OpenID logins on Facebook itself? I have only used JanRain's RPXNow up to now, so integrating directly with OpenID is new to me.

- As of December 2010, does Facebook support OpenID logins on external sites with a Facebook account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook is an Relying Party, so you can sign in to facebook using an OpenID.
Is is not a provider, however, so you can't sign in to other websites using your facebook account - at least not using OpenID.

Comment: +1 Thanks for clearing up the distinction between Relying Party and an OpenID Provider.

Comment: @Mewp Is it still true as of now?

Comment: @Pacerier: It appears so (to the extent that [facebook authentication page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) doesn't mention openid at all). You can always use an [openid-to-facebook proxy](http://facebook-openid.appspot.com/), but be sure to investigate the security implications of using such a service. The best option would be to use OAuth yourself if you need to authenticate with facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is not an OpenID provider. There is no OpenID from Facebook you can use on other pages to login. But there are some third party servers that work as proxies. You connect them to Facebook and they provide an OpenID. In the end you have an OpenID if you are logged into Facebook.

Facebook is not even an OpenID customer. There is no page where you could enter your OpenID to login on Facebook.
Yes, you can set up OpenID providers, Google or some other services as so called "*Linked accounts*". They promise: "*If you are logged into one of the accounts below you will automatically be logged into Facebook.*" But it does not work and it technically can not work as long as Facebook does not ask for the OpenID.